# YII URL how to generate new URL

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, yii-routing

I have one site in which I want URL like `SiteURL/about.html.`

I have changed code in `config/main.php` but when I login to site then gets session expired when I navigate to any other page.

If comment this code `'showScriptName'=>false` in `config/main.php` file, then its work fine and now my login session is saved and us not expired however now my URL is becoming like this `SiteURL/index.php/about.html`

But I want URL like `about.html.`

I have also one another controller for game option which URL is like: http://www.demo.com/index.php/Games/info/9.html but I want URL like SiteURL/black-hook.html in this "black-hook" is the name of the game.

```
'urlManager'=>array( 
          'urlFormat'=>'path', 
          'showScriptName'=>FALSE, 
          'rules'=>array(
                 '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
                 '<view>'=>'array('site/page')',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
           ), 
     ),
```

*SiteURL = http://www.demo.com

Comment: Post your .htaccess please.

Comment: Btw. why ".html"??? Yii is PHP based!

Answer (score 0):

First to get .html appended to your pages you need to use fake url suffix option in urlManager

This can be done by adding `'urlSuffix' =>'.html'` to your `urlManager` config like this

```
'urlManager'=>array( 
          'urlFormat'=>'path', 
          'showScriptName'=>false, 
           'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
          'rules'=>array(
                 '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
                 '<view>'=>'site/page',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
           ),
     ),
```

Secondly for hiding index.php (called the entry script) in your URL in addition to changing configuration here you need to change configuration in your apache/nginx server.

Create the file /.htaccess with the following content and save it

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Next verify if the `AllowOveride All` is there for your app directory in your apache configuration file You can also add the above configuration directly to your apache configuration file using Directory element without using .htaccess . 
**Note:** For this to work you need to have rewrite engine enabled in apache config, You can do so with the following set of commands

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Finally Restart apache2 after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your i have tried it but some time user become session Logout, and user can not login in site, can you please help me on that is there i am missing anything here?